# ASP Filter function -> C# equivalent function

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Currently at work I need to translate an old ASP-page to C# (asp.net).
On the asp-page I came across the filter function and I was wondering if C# had an equivalent function for it?

```
b = Filter(servicePeriodsArray,CStr(Year(billingDate) & Month(billingDate)))
```

Yesterday I translated this into the following piece of code.

```
string lookup1 = billingDate.Year.ToString() + billingDate.Month.ToString();
          for (int k = 0; k < servicePeriodsArray.Length; k++)
          {
              if (servicePeriodsArray[k].Contains(lookup1))
              {
                   b[c] = servicePeriodsArray[k];
                   c++;
              }
          }
```

Since I'm a complete 'noob' in the old ASP language I was wondering if my translation is a correct one.
If anyone of you guys know a equivalent function for C# for the ASP-function Filter, please let me know or if you guys could help me with the translation that would be awesome.

Kind Regards
Kevin

Comment: The is no native function called `Filter` in VBScript.  So whilst you have two answers so far which are likely to be on the right path they a) return an `IEnumerable` which `Filter` is unlikely to actuall do (it will likely be returning an array) and b) there are too many unknowns, perhaps you should find the code for `Filter` and either convert that or post it here if you are having difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Using the LINQ Where operator would be the simplest way.

```
string lookup1 = billingDate.Year.ToString() + billingDate.Month.ToString();
var b = servicePeriodsArray.Where(i => i.Contains(lookup1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = servicePeriodsArray.Where(value = value.Contains(billingDate.Year.ToString() + billingDate.Month.ToString());
```